# why doesn't mathtype show the correct formula in the browser?

Tags: html, mathjax, mathtype

I am using mathjax and mathtype to put some formula in my webpage. But for the following formula, the browser put it in a bordered square and shows the Tex text instead.

> $$\left\langle {\Psi }  \mathrel{\left | {\vphantom {\Psi  \Phi }} 
>   \right. \kern-\nulldelimiterspace}  {\Phi } \right\rangle $$

Any help to solve this problem is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `\kern-\nulldelimiterspace`.  MathJax does't implement  the `\nulldelimiterspace` macro, and its value in MathJax is 0 anyway, so there is no need for that `\kern` in MathJax.